# Having troubles using sort function with STL List for c++, how can i improve it?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, c++14

This is all in the header file, and in main its pretty simple, I declare a list and then populate it, with no issues, and can print the list from another function that I have in the header file no problems, but the issue comes with the sort function. It keeps saying that it

> Severity Code Description Project File Line   Suppression State
>   Error C2664 'bool (Bike *,Bike *)': 
>  cannot convert argument 2
>   from '_Value_type' to 'Bike *' Project7 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xutility  1481

```
//the argument for the sort function

bool comp_id(Bike* b1, Bike* b2)
{
    return b1->id_num < b2->id_num;
}


//This is how I plan on sorting it.
// Also, side note can I do list<Bike> secondList = head; and then sort secondList.sort(comp_id)?

        head.sort(comp_id);
        for (auto iterator = head.begin(); iterator != head.end(); ++iterator)
        {
            cout << iterator->id_num << endl;
        }

//This is the Structure 

struct Bike
{
    char manufact[25];
    int id_num;
    status rented_code; //RENTED/NOT_RENTED
    char to_whom[25];   //to whom bike is rented
    int size;
    float cost_per_day;
    bool deleted;   //to mark bike as deleted in the list.
    Bike* next_manuf;   //pointer to next node in the
                //manufacturers list
    Bike* next_id;  //pointer to the next node
            //in the list by ID
    Bike* next; //pointer to the next node in the general list
};
```

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions with the C tag.

Comment: what is `head`?

Comment: So why did you write your comparison function to use pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *head* is a *list<Bike>* your compare function is wrong, it must be

```
bool comp_id(Bike & b1, Bike & b2)
{
  return b1.id_num < b2.id_num;
}
```

or better

```
bool comp_id(const Bike & b1, const Bike & b2)
{
  return b1.id_num < b2.id_num;
}
```

---

Your compare function would be ok if *head* was a *list<Bike *>*

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely helps, as it now runs as intend, but for whatever reason, it throws a little note "cannot determine which instance of overloaded function is intended" even though it'll still compile, why does it do that? Also, why must I do it that way over the first way I started. What is going on with the pointers?

Comment: @TreyHitchcock for which line the little note is generated ?

Comment: @TreyHitchcock did you modified *comp_id* or you added the second definition still having your original ? If you added the second definition rename the function having the old definition (using pointer)

Comment: It is at the part head.sort(comp_id); It still compiles, but in visual studio it makes a comment on it,and all i did was modify it, I only have one com_id function. Also, I modified it to the second version.

Comment: @TreyHitchcock do you use `bool comp_id(Bike & b1, Bike & b2)` or `bool comp_id(const Bike & b1, const Bike & b2)` ? If you use the first  change for the second

Comment: bool comp_id(const Bike & b1, const Bike & b2)
{
 return b1.id_num < b2.id_num;
} That is exactly it

Comment: @TreyHitchcock this is very strange, may be there are two versions of `sort` ? Sorry to insist but may be you also have a declaration of `comp_id` you forgot to change ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is only one, but this is new to me in this class, there will be another bool function but that will be to sort by manufacturer, and has a different name.

Comment: AH!!!! I figured it out, I checked my source and I had the original function deceleration there, I got rid of that and it fixed the problem! sorry about that and thank you!

Comment: @TreyHitchcock that is what I said in my previous remark ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's what prompted my search, I never would have figured it out otherwise. Thank you so much! But, my final question is, why does this version work and the original I had didn't?

Comment: @TreyHitchcock what you mean 'original', the one with the pointer ? Because it is not compatible with the type of your list. You use a list of Bike, not a list of pointer to Bike

Comment: Ah, so I was trying to use a list of pointers of type Bike, not a pointer to a list of Bike structures?

Comment: @TreyHitchcock your original version of *comp_id* was only compatible with a list of pointer to Bike yes, this is what I say at the end of my answer ;-) But your list is a list of Bike